# Xcode7でiPhone6以降のレイアウトが崩れてしまいます

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, xcode7

Xcode7にアップデートした後、iPhone6以降のモデルのサイズ・レイアウトが崩れてしまいます。 
（実機・シミュレータともに）

Tartget→General→App Icons and Launch Imagesの３つをそれぞれ

①アップデート前：AppIcon、LaunchImage、空欄 
②アップデート後：AppIcon、LaunchImage、Launch Image 
のように設定していました。

①では6,6sにも対応し、②では5sまでしか対応しませんでした。 
LaunchScreen.storyboardを追加する方法も試しましたが、 
WatchOS storyboards do not support target device type 'iPhone' 
のエラーが出てしまい、その後進めることができませんでした。 
こちらのエラーの解決方法も調べましたが、わかりませんでした....

iPhone6以降にもサイズを対応させるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/18315 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

まず`WatchOS storyboards do not support target device type 'iPhone'`こちらのエラーですが、おそらくwatchOS用のStoryboardがiPhone App用のスキームでビルドされているのではないでしょうか。
Storyboardの設定で「Target Membership」を確認してみてください。

様々な画面サイズに対応させるには、Auto Layoutを使いましょう。iOS7以降から利用できる機能です。現在はiPadも含め様々な画面サイズの端末が登場しているので、Auto Layoutの対応はほぼ必須だと考えてよいでしょう。余力がありましたら、Size Classesも有効にして画面の回転やiPadのSplit View（マルチタスキング）対応もしてみるのもよいかとおもいます。